# Refactor common string values in page to some EL constant

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

In a JSF component what is the best way to "refactor" common constants, e.g. names/paths in a `<h:graphicImage>` tag to a single local, temporary property?

```
<ui:composite>

  <h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="/a/b/c/img1.png"/>
  <h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="/a/b/c/img2.png"/>
  <h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="/a/b/c/img3.png"/>
  <!-- ... lots of repetitions -->

</ui:composite>
```

should be

```
<ui:composite>

  <-- assign /a/b/c/ to path -->

  <h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{path}img1.png"/>
  <h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{path}img2.png"/>
  <h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{path}img3.png"/>
  <!-- ... lots of repetitions -->

</ui:composite>
```

Comment: To be more precise: besides using static entities... Imagine "path" beeing computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/set.html) on application scope. This basically stores the variable in the [application map](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getApplicationMap()).

```
<c:set var="path" value="a/b/c/" scope="application" />
<h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{path}img1.png"/>
<h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{path}img2.png"/>
<h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{path}img3.png"/>
```

Make sure that the `var="path"` doesn't conflict with existing managed bean names or implicit EL variables and such. You could if necessary use a convention to prefix it with `_`.

```
<c:set var="_path" value="a/b/c/" scope="application" />
<h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{_path}img1.png"/>
<h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{_path}img2.png"/>
<h:graphicImage library="mylib" name="#{_path}img3.png"/>
```

Comment: while this is a little counterinuitive it works. so ui:param simply writes the result of evaluation to request scope?

Comment: Some words would be nice about why this is the best alternative and if this is best for constants under all circumstances!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a composite component.  Then you don't have to change the img1.png, img2.png, ... etc all over the place when that changes.  The path can the be supplied as a parameter.

Comment: This is from an automatic migration - i have only limited selection on the idioms that match the original code. Thank's for the tip anyway.